# How do we configure module wise configuration in logstash of ELK

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need to create a module wise dashboard like User management, campaign management. How do I configure in logstash to pull all logs from different log files?

### Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl  => false
  }
  file {
        path => "C:\data\logs\OCDE.log"
        type => "ocde"
    }
    file {
        path => "C:\data\logs\CLM.log"
        type => "clm"
    }
}

filter {

         if [type] == "ocde"{
        grok {
            match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"]
        }
     }
     else if [type] == "clm" {
        grok {
            match => [ "message" , "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"]
        }
     }

   }


output {
    if (document_type= backendlog) {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            manage_template => false
            index => "enliven_be_log_yyyymmdd"
            document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can glob (i.e. look for *.log) or have several instance of logstash with different config. It's not clear from your question what you want

Comment: I have multiple module log files which I need to configure it as module wise in logstash to pull data and display in Kibana dashboard. also, how do we add the filter conditions for the same?